# How to take screenshot of expandable uitableview programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ipad

I tried to take screenshot of expandable uitableview, I tried to take a screenshot of uitableview but I was not able do that , then I changed tableview frame size to tableview content size. After taking screenshot I changed frame size to old frame size. Now the problem is that I am having expandable section in table view. I'm able to take screenshot of unexpanded table view cell in  my screenshot. I need to take the screenshot of unexpanded table view cell content too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using this category file u can take the screen shot what ever visible in the screen....

```
  @interface UIImage (MyImage)


    + (UIImage*)imageFromView:(UIView*)view;
    + (UIImage*)imageFromView:(UIView*)view scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
    + (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
    + (void)beginImageContextWithSize:(CGSize)size;
    + (UIImage *)croppedImage:(UIImage *)myImage :(CGRect)bounds;
    @end

#import "UIImage+MyImage.h"

@implementation UIImage (MyImage)

+ (void)beginImageContextWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0) {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, YES, 2.0);
        } else {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
        }
    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    }
}

+ (void)endImageContext
{
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}

+ (UIImage*)imageFromView:(UIView*)view
{
    [self beginImageContextWithSize:[view bounds].size];
    BOOL hidden = [view isHidden];
    [view setHidden:NO];
    [[view layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [self endImageContext];
    [view setHidden:hidden];
    return image;
}

+ (UIImage*)imageFromView:(UIView*)view scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    UIImage *image = [self imageFromView:view];
    if ([view bounds].size.width != newSize.width ||
        [view bounds].size.height != newSize.height) {
        image = [self imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:newSize];
    }
    return image;
}

+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    [self beginImageContextWithSize:newSize];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [self endImageContext];
    return newImage;
}


+ (UIImage *)croppedImage:(UIImage *)myImage :(CGRect)bounds {
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(myImage.CGImage, bounds);
    UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGSize asd =  croppedImage.size;
    return croppedImage;
}

@end
```

the method call will be....

```
 yourImageView.image= [UIImage imageFromView:(UIView*)yourTableViewInstance ]
```

try this....

Comment: And also i tired different way to solve this problem. At the time of taking screen shot i expanded all the sections in the table view. And i used content size of table view to take screen shot. It works fine for me..